# Converting Integer to dynamically allocated Char array, digit by digit using pointers

Tags: c, array, pointers

> Problem: Write a function to convert Integer to String, using only
>   pointers, without array indexes, string must be dynamically
>   allocated.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// move each character in array one place to the right
// we need to make place for new character on the left
void moveArrayElementsRight(char *ptr, int len) {
    for (int j = len; j > 1; j--) {
        *(ptr + j - 1) = *(ptr + j - 2);
    }
}

void intToStr(int myNumber, char* myString){
    int i = 1;    //track size of allocated memory
    bool isMinus = false;

    if (myNumber < 0) {

        myNumber *= -1;    //without this (myNumber % 10) + '0' wont work
        isMinus = true;
    }

    if (myNumber == 0){    //special case for 0

        myString = (char*)realloc(myString, ((i + 1) * sizeof(char)));
        *myString = '0';
        *(myString + 1) = '\0';
    }

    while (myNumber != 0) {

        myString = (char*)realloc(myString, ((i + 1) * sizeof(char)));  //increse memory =+1 for next digit
        i++;
        moveArrayElementsRight(myString, i);
        *myString = (myNumber % 10) + '0'; //put digit to array
        myNumber /= 10;
    }

    if (isMinus) {

        myString = (char*)realloc(myString, ((i + 1) * sizeof(char)));  //increse memory =+1 for '-' sign
        i++;
        moveArrayElementsRight(myString, i);
        *myString = '-'; //put sign at the beginning
    }
}

int main() {

    int numberToConvert = -10;
    char *numberAsString = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));  //create empty array, with place only for '\0'
    *numberAsString = '\0';    //mark the end of array

    intToStr(numberToConvert, numberAsString);

    printf("%s", numberAsString);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to cast to `(char*)` when you `malloc()` or `realloc()`. It works perfectly fine without the casts. You should make it a habit to `free()` allocated memory on the heap to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @Phrancis That sounds like the beginning of a helpful answer.

Comment: There's two things I would change, 1) Pre-allocate sufficient space to eliminate the need to realloc, and 2) Just place digits and optionally the minus sign on the right and reverse the string at the end.

Answer (score 3):

### Issues Concerning Allocation

It is not necessary to cast the result of a call to `malloc()` in C, and many consider this to be a more error-prone style. It is easier to write correctly, read, and maintain the allocation line if you write it like this:

```
char *numberAsString = malloc(sizeof(*numberAsString));
```

This way, if the type is changed at some point in the future, there is only one place you need to update, versus three places to update in your version.

I would also suggest moving the allocation from `main()` into the `intToStr()` function (which is already reallocating the memory), and returning a pointer to the allocated memory to the calling function. This would necessitate changing the function signature of `intToStr()` to:

```
char * intToStr(int myNumber, char* myString);
```

Then in `main()`, you should declare:

```
char *numberAsString = NULL;
```

The same advice given above for `malloc()` applies to the calls to `realloc()` in the function `intToStr()`. Additionally, `realloc()` returns a `NULL` pointer in the event of an error. By assigning the return value directly to `myString` you risk leaking memory by losing the pointer to the previous allocation. You should store the return value of `realloc()` in a temporary variable, and then assign it to `myString` if it is non-null.

Continuing with allocation issues, I would consider `malloc`ing enough memory to hold any `int` number-string (really, I would suggest using an `int32_t` number-- see below) at the beginning of `intToStr()`. Then, before returning the pointer to this memory, you can `realloc()` to the size of the actual number-string, i.e.:

```
number_string_sz = 12;  // for int32_t plus space for `-` and `\0`

myString = malloc(number_string_sz);

...

temp = realloc(myString, strlen(myString) + 1);
if (temp) {
    myString = temp;
}
```

You may wish to return a `NULL` pointer from `intToStr()` if there is an allocation error, and let the caller handle the error. Of course, the caller is responsible for `free`ing allocated memory.

### Integer Overflow

Note that it is possible that `myNumber` is equal to `INT_MIN`, and then the line `myNumber *= -1;` would lead to integer overflow (invoking undefined behavior for `signed` integer types). Consider using a fixed-width type, such as `int32_t`, that is passed into the function, and copy this to a larger fixed-width type (`int64_t`) for a working copy within the function. The reasoning here is that the widths of the integer types are implementation-dependent, and even `long int` is only guaranteed to be *at least* as wide as `int`. By choosing specific widths for your integer types, you can protect against integer overflow in your calculations. The `int64_t` type is larger than `int32_t`, so the smallest value which can be held by an `int32_t`, when stored in an `int64_t`, can safely be multiplied by `-1`.